# Set limit to selected rows from DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, conditional-statements, findall

I want to get from DB last five rows, but I cant do that. I trying to find solution but I didnt get any results. I want to write something like this:

```
$this->getDotrine->getRepository('Entity')->findAll(...);
```

`->slice()` not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should limit the number of results on the database level, ie. in Doctrine's DQL query. Create a custom method within your `Entity` repository:

```
public function findLatest($limit) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: All you need is access to the `EntityManager` and it's [`createQueryBuilder()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#313-321) method (this is what [`EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder()` does](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L79)). `EntityManager` is available as `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` service or `$this->getDoctrine()->getObjectManager()` from within a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
    $qb->setMaxResults();
```

e.g.

// Controller

```
   $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('nameandbundle:entity')->findAllWithLimit(10);
```

so in your respostiory class for that entity simply type;

```
   function findAllWithLimit($limit) {

       return $this->getEntityManager()
                   ->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->select('e')
                   ->setMaxResults($limit)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();
    }
```

You can do this without a repository but do not recommend this as you should follow fat models thin controllers. But you would do it like this.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $results = $qb->select('e')
                   ->from('youbundle:entity', 'e')
                   ->setMaxResults(10)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();
```